# R custom predict algorithm implementation problem

Tags: r, arrays, algorithm, time-series, prediction

Let's say I have a series c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and a model that can predict another number basing on "m" last numbers. We split the series in proportion 5:5 (training, testing). Then I need to write a function that does the predictions over time. What I have is:

```
predictor <- function(data, model, m){
 low <- length(data) * 1/2
 high <- length(data) - 1
 predictions <- c()
 for (i in low:high){
  a <- i - m + 1
  predictions <- append(predictions, predict(model, data[a : i]))
 }
 return(predictions)
}
```

Is this function actually correct? And can it be done in any better way? Unfortunately the `predict(model, newdata=testing, h=1)` will not work here.

Comment: No, generally speaking your function is not right, `predict` is a generic and its methods need objects of class `"data.frame"`, `"environment"` or `"list"` passed as `newdata`. If you pass it an atomic vector like `c(1, etc, 10)` then `predict` methods will give an error.

Comment: Even if you replace `length` by `NROW` and pass `newdata = data[a:i, , drop = FALSE]`, the loop is wrong, you are repeating indices as `a` is incremented by 1 each iteration. The output will be a sequence of length `m` per each `i`.